# How to pull data from one table to another table based on certain condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I've two tables. Table one is named `RAW` and table two is named `REPORT`. Please see below screenshots. Both the tables are in Relationship with Column name `REQUESTID`, however the only difference is - `REPORT.REQUESTID` is `DISTINCT` of `RAW.REQUESTID` and rest of the fields of `REPORT` table are blank.

I'm looking for Query to fill data in `REPORT` table but my conditions are

To `INSERT` Data in *`NEW`* Column

> ```
> REPORT.REQUESTID = RAW.REQUESTID AND RAW.LASTSTATUS= "NEW"
> ```

When above condition is true, `REPORT.NEW` should have the value from `RAW.LASTUPDATEON` for their `REQUESTID`. Result will look like in the screenshot which I've manually filled.

[Tables and Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEBpx.jpg)

Comment: Can anyone please help? Looking for Update Query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. Here's the query I was looking for.

```
UPDATE MAIN 
INNER JOIN RAW ON MAIN.REQUESTID=RAW.REQUESTID 
SET MAIN.NEW = [RAW].[LASTUPDATEON]
WHERE RAW.LASTSTATUS='NEW';
```

Answer (score 0):

The query will be something like this

```
INSERT INTO REPORT (REQUESTID, NEW) SELECT REQUESTID, LASTUPDATEDON
FROM RAW WHERE LASTSTATUS = "NEW"
```

To insert values that are not present in table

```
INSERT INTO REPORT (REQUESTID, NEW) SELECT REQUESTID, LASTUPDATEDON
FROM RAW WHERE LASTSTATUS = "NEW" AND REQUESTID NOT IN (SELECT REQUESTID FROM REPORT)
```

Comment: Great! It's working but here's the problem. It's also adding the Request ID. However the REQUESTID are already there in the table. But I just need the other values for the request ID.

Comment: So you need values that are not present in table? Updated my answer

Comment: No, ok.. the actuall data I have is more than a million. The values from Column `(RAW.LASTSTATUS)` are going to be column name in `REPORT` table. and I'm trying to find out the time for that particular `REQUESTID` and `LASTSTATUS`.

I've made a query to copy `REQUESTID` from `RAW` table to `REPORT` table. Now I need another query to pull the time based on the `REQUESTID` and `LASTSTATUS` from `RAW` Table to put it in `NEW` column for same `REQUESTID`. same way I'll amend the query for other columns.

Did I get any luck to present my requirement?